# jQuery - Check if div has content, if not add class to top level div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm really hoping someone can help me. I am having issues with this page: http://dd-server.co.uk/vinetrail/producers/

Each region has a number of producers which are shown via collapsible divs. It's all working fine, but when you use the filter at the top of the page, it still works fine except the empty regions are still shown.

I want to use jQuery to detect the empty divs and hide the whole region, so only regions with producers are shown. Here is my code:

```
<div id="producer-list">            
            <?php
                $region_group_terms = get_terms( 'producer_region' );
                $c = 0;
                $id = 'section1';

                foreach ( $region_group_terms as $region_group_term ) {
                    $c++;
                    $producers_query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => 'producers',                         
                        'orderby'   => 'title',
                        'order'     => 'ASC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'producer_region',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array( $region_group_term->slug ),
                                'operator' => 'IN'
                            )
                        ),
                        'search_filter_id'  => 788
                    ) );
                ?>

                <div class="pro-wrap">                  
                    <?php if($c == 1) : ?>
                        <div class="collapsible collapse-open" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><h2><?php echo $region_group_term->name; ?><span></span></h2></div>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <div class="collapsible" id="<?php echo $region_group_term->name; ?>"><h2><?php echo $region_group_term->name; ?><span></span></h2></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="content">
                                <?php
                                    if ( $producers_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $producers_query->have_posts() ) : $producers_query->the_post(); ?>
                                        <div class="one-quarter">                                           
                                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/producer-default.jpg" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <h3>
                                                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $region_group_term->name; ?>
                                                    <span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>                                           
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                                <?php
                                    $member_group_query = null;
                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check the content with `$(".something").text()`

Comment: It returns an empty string if the content is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, in jQuery

> Try 1

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  // Loop over hidden element with class container 
  jQuery.each(jQuery('.pro-wrap .container:hidden'), function(i, ele){
    // Hide closest parent found with class pro-wrap
    jQuery(ele).closest('.pro-wrap').hide();
  });
});
```

> Try 2

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  // Loop over element with class content 
  jQuery.each(jQuery('.pro-wrap .container .content'), function(i, ele){
    var jEle = jQuery(ele);
    // If empty content
    if (jEle.text().trim().length == 0) {
      // Hide closest parent found with class pro-wrap
      jEle.closest('.pro-wrap').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work as all of the collapsed divs start off hidden so it was only showing the first one as that is default open.

Comment: I did try the two suggestions together i.e. jQuery.each(jQuery('.pro-wrap .content').text(), function(i, ele){   
       jQuery(ele).closest('.pro-wrap').hide();
      });  but that didn't work either

Comment: I add a second try, fingers cross! :-)

Comment: You are an absolute star!!! Whoop it worked, I only had to make one change and that was to add var as jEle was an undeclared variable, so: var  jEle = jQuery(ele);

Comment: Perfect! I edit my answer to include your comment. With time and patience we can achieve everything! 
Sinon j'aime bien la liste des régions françaises, je vais la récupérer ;-)